# File (Field) Paths get year only

Tags: 7, files

I've recently found and started using the File Fields Path module in Drupal 7 and I have a date field that I'm only collecting the year from.  Using that in the file path part of the module, it returns the value as YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS.

So a value of 2017 shows up as 2017-01-01-000000 since I didn't collect any of the other information.

Is there a way to just get it to make the folder as 2017 instead of the whole date?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the manage fields area for that field - something like admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_field_path

and for the "file path" setting, enter [current-date:custom:Y].

This is untested, but *should* work. Get back to me if it doesn't.

Comment: That works for getting the current year.  I'm hoping to get the year from a date field that the user enters the year so it doesn't have to be the current year.

Comment: As a side note - you don't need the file fields path module for the current date to work.  The file field path module gives you the ability to get information from fields and node information - such as the title, node id, values in the fields, etc. which are not available in the default token list.

Comment: Sorry you're totally right. Slow moment from me. You should be able to use the same idea and use this token [node:field-issue-date:custom:Y] (Replacing issue date with your field name of course)

Comment: Sorry it took me awhile to get back to you - I've been away from my office.  This doesn't work unfortunately.  It says that it is using an invalid token.